# Принятие данных с php в js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Пробую принять данные, но почему-то undefined.

Вот отправка:

```
    $arr = array (
        'status_delete' => $status_delete,
    );

    $result_delete = json_encode($arr);
    echo $result_delete;
```

потом вроде есть отправка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот на деле undefined

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/delete-item-debet.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

                      console.log(data.status_delete);

                                   }
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: `console.log(data);`?

Comment: а что data?? мне надо получить status_delete что пришол

Comment: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); ...` - что в консоли?

Comment: попадаєт в error: почемуто

Comment: потому что "integer<br>{status_delete: 0}" -  невалидный JSON

Comment: попробуй сделать так  ** echo json_encode($arr);**

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что вы выводите какой-то ещё код до показа JSON. Потому он приходит в таком виде, что видно в отладке:

```
integer<br>{status_delete: 0}
```

Естественно такой JSON не может распарсить никто. Кроме, разве что, Чака Норриса. Это легко проверить:

```
var_dump(json_decode('integer<br>{"status_delete": 0}'));
```

Выведет `NULL`; для сравнения:

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"status_delete": 0}'));
```

Выведет положенное:

```
class stdClass#1 (1) {
  public $status_delete =>
  int(0)
}
```